# Can we use sockets functions `send()/recv()` as thread-safe queue MP-MC (multi-producer / multi-consumer)?

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, networking

As we know:

1. sockets functions `send()/recv()` are thread-safe (lock-based with mutex):

   - [Are parallel calls to send/recv on the same socket valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981372/are-parallel-calls-to-send-recv-on-the-same-socket-valid)
   - [is winsock2 thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13983398/is-winsock2-thread-safe)
2. these sockets functions use queue for non-blocking send data

And then, can we use sockets functions `send()/recv()` as thread-safe queue MP-MC (multi-producer / multi-consumer)?

Comment: As I understood your question correct, It isn't threadsafe.

Comment: @Zaibis  "POSIX defines send/recv as atomic operations, so assuming you're talking about POSIX send/recv then **yes, you can call them simultaneously from multiple threads and things will work**." http://stackoverflow.com/a/1981439/1558037

Comment: At least I'm not talking about POSIX. But anyway maybe I just misunderstood what you are mentioning by "queue". But as I think then to constructs as `kqueue()` (which isn't thread safe) then it isn't.

Comment: Yeah - maybe it could work with UDP messaging, but it seems like a particularly slow and inefficient mechanism for inter-thread comms when compared with a 'normal' producer-consumer queue.

Comment: @Zaibis  No any words about `kqueue()`. Only about: many threads do `send()` and many threads do `recv()`, and all this instead of thread-safe MP-MC-queue, will does it work?

Comment: @Martin James  Thanks. But why not with TCP? And if we use this for data transfer between processes on a single server, will be it fast as 'normal' producer-consumer queue (lock-based)?

Comment: @Alex - because TCP transfer requires a server<>client connection to be set up and one such connection would be unable to transfer messages larger than one byte without them getting mixed up in a multiple-consumer situation.  Also, with inter-thread comms, or inter-process comms via shared memory, a 'normal' P-C queue will be much faster - often, it only needs to queue up one pointer and so there is no bulk copying and a very short lock time.

Comment: @Martin James  Do you mean that UDP sends data in a strict sequence, but TCP can send unordered data, even if we are connecting to localhost?
And sockets will have more overhead, because will be used not one, but two thread-safe queues: one for the `send()`, and one for `recv()`?

Comment: @Alex - UDP transfers datagrams - complete messages.  TCP transfers a byte stream.  To transfer messages larger than one byte requires extra protocol on top of TCP.  Sockets have more overhead because, well, they are a complex state-machine with several layers, (though your localhost transfer would probably begin and end at L2/3). It's a bit of a sledgehammer to use for comms on one box.

Comment: @Martin James  Do you mean that we must use `SOCK_SEQPACKET` as type in `int socket(int domain, int type, int protocol);` for guarantee that client received datagram as complete message via UDP?

Comment: @Alex: UDP can only be SOCK_DGRAM, and is not reliable (you can lose datagrams). SOCK_SEQPACKET is reliable and preserves message boundaries. SCTP supports SOCK_SEQPACKET sockets.